# How to check contact "type" that is saved in contacts list in android

Tags: android

I am new in android programming, I want to know how to check the contact type from the contact list that is saved in Android Contact List, that it is Skype contact or Whatsapp contact or Viber and others?

Answer (score 0):

The ContactsContract.StreamItems and ContactsContract.StreamItemPhotos tables manage incoming data from social networks.

You can check out this link - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStream

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you show me example code how to get that the contact is from skype or other?